# Issue in calling script synchronously from webview2 in WPF

Tags: c#, multithreading, webview2

We have a WPF application using WebView2 where one of the flows need a call originating from the WPF app to call a JS function asynchronously. The JS function in turn will call a C# method in the Host Object Proxy class which would eventually need to call another JS function but this time the call would need to be synchronous. So the call flow is something like below:

1. C# code calls JS function async
2. JS function calls C# code in host
3. object proxy Host object proxy method in C# would call a JS function
   synchronously

A sample workflow could be a Save button in the WPF app which calls some JS function which calls back to a C# method defined in the host object proxy which needs to do a dirty check in the JS layer and hence calls another JS function. The last JS function call needs to be synchronous as it is existing code where async/await pattern introduction will lead to lot of changes.

The method that we have been using to convert a asynchronous script execution call to synchronous in the WPF app is as below:

```
public static T WaitWithMessagePumping<T>(Task<T> asyncAction)
    {
        DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        asyncAction.ContinueWith(t => frame.Continue = false);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
        return asyncAction.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

This has worked well for calls which are originating from the WPF side.
But since the call in question is actually being invoked from JS (we can see a native to managed transition in the call stack), the applications stops responding when the code reaches the Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame) API call (seems to go into deadlock).

So essentially the issue is how do we call a script synchronously from C# when the call is originating in the context of a JS function calling a host object method?

simple project link which replicates the situation: [Gitlab url](https://gitlab.com/software.koder/synccall.git)

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me,
if your host object has a :

```
public void DoStuffAsync()
{
   var tmp = WaitWithMessagePumping(webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("box1.value = '123';");  
}
```

Instead do this :

```
public void DoStuffAsync()
{
   webView2.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => 
      { var tmp = WaitWithMessagePumping(webView2.ExecuteScript("box1.value = '123'")));};
}
```

It works fine.